# r error bars and y axis labels not in order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a plot to show the estimates and CI graphically. Right now my estimates and y axis labels are out of synch on the plot.

If this is my dataset.

```
       Group      Est     conf.low      conf.high   pvalue   
       Bi         1.12    0.65          1.603       0.000
       Di        -0.24   -0.44         -0.038       0.02
       Dn        -0.47   -0.80         -0.140       0.005
       HMD       -0.006  -0.32          0.311       0.968
       HMS        0.72   -1.00         -0.436       0.000
       LM        -0.055  -0.32          0.214       0.6886
       PaS       -1.31   -1.79         -0.850       0.000
       Ph A       0.065  -0.250         0.381       0.6885
       TRB        1.023   0.63          1.41        0.000
       TRC       -0.599  -0.94         -0.249       0.0008
```

What I am seeing is a plot like this below where the y axis labels and estimates are completely out of order.
[image]

This is my code

```
     ggplot(df, aes(y = row.names(df), x= Est))+
        geom_point(shape = 16, size =5)+
          scale_y_discrete(label = df$Group) + 
             geom_errobarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), width =0, size = 1)+
               geom_vline(xintercept=1, color="black", linetype = "dashed", cex=1, alpha=0.5)
```

Any help on how to sync my y-axis labels with the estimates is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: In row `HMS`, `Est` is not between `conf.low` and `conf.high`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the plot to appear in the same order as the data in your data frame, then you need to plot `Group` on the y axis, but first convert it to a factor whose levels are the reverse of the column `Group`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y = factor(Group, rev(Group)), x = Est)) +
  geom_point(shape = 16, size = 5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Est), nudge_y = 0.3, size = 4) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), height = 0, size = 1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", cex = 1, alpha = 0.5) +
  labs(y = "Group") +
  theme_gray(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Group = c("Bi", "Di", "Dn", "HMD", "HMS", "LM", 
"PaS", "Ph A", "TRB", "TRC"), Est = c(1.12, -0.24, -0.47, -0.006, 
-0.72, -0.055, -1.31, 0.065, 1.023, -0.599), conf.low = c(0.65, 
-0.44, -0.8, -0.32, -1, -0.32, -1.79, -0.25, 0.63, -0.94), conf.high = c(1.603, 
 -0.038, -0.14, 0.311, -0.436, 0.214, -0.85, 0.381, 1.41, -0.249
), pvalue = c(0, 0.02, 0.005, 0.968, 0, 0.6886, 0, 0.6885, 0, 
8e-04)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo it should be `geom_errorbarh` . also fixing `Est` value at row `HMS` to `-0.72`

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y = row.names(df), x= Est))+
   geom_point(shape = 16, size =5)+
   scale_y_discrete(label = df$Group) +
   geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), width =0, size = 1)+
   geom_vline(xintercept=1, color="black", linetype = "dashed", cex=1, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Credits:** I had forgotten the values above the points, correction copy&pasted from [Allan Cameron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74248972/8245406).

Here is a solution with `reorder` to put the y axis in order of the bars mid points, `Est`.

```r
df1<-"Group      Est     conf.low      conf.high   pvalue   
       Bi         1.12    0.65          1.603       0.000
       Di        -0.24   -0.44         -0.038       0.02
       Dn        -0.47   -0.80         -0.140       0.005
       HMD       -0.006  -0.32          0.311       0.968
       HMS        -0.72   -1.00         -0.436       0.000
       LM        -0.055  -0.32          0.214       0.6886
       PaS       -1.31   -1.79         -0.850       0.000
       'Ph A'       0.065  -0.250         0.381       0.6885
       TRB        1.023   0.63          1.41        0.000
       TRC       -0.599  -0.94         -0.249       0.0008"
df1 <- read.table(textConnection(df1), header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df1, aes(x = Est, y = reorder(Group, -Est))) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Est), nudge_y = 0.3, size = 4) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
  ylab("Group")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And with error bars, instead of line bars. This time the points need an explicit call to `geom_point`.

```r
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Est, y = reorder(Group, -Est))) +
  geom_point(pch = 16, size = 5) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf.low, xmax = conf.high), height = 0.5, size = 1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Est), nudge_y = 0.3, size = 4) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1, linetype = "dashed", alpha = 0.5) +
  ylab("Group")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>